# wrong version off gcc in my sytem for a python build

Tags: python, linux, gcc

I am trying to install a software package in my linux environment in a local directory . The package requires gcc version 4.9 or later and python 3.5 or later as . I have python 3.7 on my environment, however only have gcc v 4.8.5 on my environment.

When I run my setup.py script, it wont work because I dont have the current compiler version.  What is ht best option to go about this install? Note that I cannot install a higher version of GCC on my environment. The best I could do is a local install that does not mess with the GCC 4.8.5 environment.

Comment: what makes you think you need a higher version of GCC? you might but what evidence do you have that this is your issue? does it actually thow an error? perhaps you could pull the project files and change setup.py to require gcc 4.8.5 instead?

Comment: Note that generally, you don't need to be able to install software _on the entire system_ to be able to install software _for your personal account_. Portage-style software installation systems are very much a thing that exist.

Comment: superuser.com may be a good place to figure out how to get user space gnu / gcc installs going.